# Nifi-API-JAVA PUT request

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I just want to start Nifi processor through REST API java code, i am able to invoke HTTP connection and able to see play button on processors but flow is not happening? and i have multiple processes group in which my first processor is GETSplunk Template which is in cron driven ,manual start is good and fine and when i start through API flow is not working, and changed to Timer schedule it is showing error for SQL template ,can any one bumped with this issue, please suggest me. 
sample API code is.

```
    String url = "http://hostname:8080/nifi-api/flow/process-groups/{id};
      URL obj = new URL(url);
      HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
     // Setting basic put request
      con.setDoOutput(true);
      con.setRequestMethod("PUT");
      con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");

      String putJsonData = "{\r\n" +
      "\"component\":{\r\n" +
      "\"id\":\"<processor-group id>\",\r\n " +"\"state\":\"RUNNING\"\r\n" + "}";
      OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(con.getOutputStream());
      wr.write(putJsonData);
      wr.flush();
      wr.close();

      int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
      System.out.println("nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
      System.out.println("Post Data : " + putJsonData);
      System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);


      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new
      InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream())); String output; StringBuffer
      response = new StringBuffer();

      while ((output = in.readLine()) != null) { response.append(output); }

      in.close();

      //printing result from response
     System.out.println(response.toString()); 
     }
```

Comment: Every action you take through the NiFi web UI invokes the REST API directly. I would recommend using your browser's developer tools to observe the exact API request the JS client takes when you perform the desired action in the UI and copy that directly.

Answer (score 0):

@Sravya99 When I need to trigger flow from outside of Nifi,  I often create a NiFi API interface listening on a port via HandleHttpRequest and HandleHttpResponse.  This can be very simple request, or very complicated with ssl, access and authorization, etc.  It should serve fine for your purpose, leaving your flow always on, and initiating the triggered responses using the HandleHttpRequest.